# Can I add conditional defines in the msbuild command line?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe2

I have the following sample code:

```
program boohoo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$IFDEF boo}
{$MESSAGE warn 'boo'}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF hoo}
{$MESSAGE warn 'hoo'}
{$ENDIF}

begin
end.
```

In the project options the conditional `boo` is defined. I would like to be able to add the conditional `hoo` as part of my msbuild command line.

I have tried it like this:

```
msbuild boohoo.dproj /p:Config=Release;DCC_Define="$(DCC_Define);hoo"
```

The output shows `hoo` but not `boo`. When I use verbose output to see the dcc32 command I see

```
-D$;hoo
```

Clearly I can do it like this:

```
msbuild boohoo.dproj /p:Config=Release;DCC_Define="boo;hoo"
```

but naturally I want to use whatever conditionals are declared in the project options *plus* what I specify on the command line.

Is there any way for me to specify this property with reference to the value from the underlying configuration?

Comment: I can reproduce the fact that it seems that you have an either-or choice here: Use the defines from the dproj, or the command line ones, but appending the one to the other appears to require you to write a utility of some kind to extract the defines for a particular build and then append to them.

Comment: @Warren You can reproduce the behaviour I describe. But I'm hoping that there might be some magic. For example, what if you could write `DCC_Define+=hoo`

Comment: You might achieve some success by hacking the Borland.Delphi.Targets msbuild configuration file.  But that seems really non-portable to me. I suspect this line: `<Defines>$(DCC_Define)</Defines>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Disclaimer: don't use MsBuild myself yet, all taken from the docs and some IDE experimentation**

According to MsBuild command line reference ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx ):

> /property:name=value
>
> Sets or overrides these project-level properties, where name is the
>   property name and value is the property value. Use a semicolon or a
>   comma to separate multiple properties, or specify each property
>   separately. /p is also acceptable. For example:
>   /property:WarningLevel=2;OutputDir=bin\Debug

setting or overriding is all you can do for a property value. Adding to a property value from the project file is either not possible or a case of a hidden feature.

But I guess what you could do is define a custom property in your dproj file with an " " as its default value:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExtraDefines> </ExtraDefines>
</PropertyGroup>
```

reference that in your defines statement

```
<DCC_Define>DUNIT;$(ExtraDefines);$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
```

which in the IDE should be `DUNIT;$(ExtraDefines)`

and then specify it on the command line:

```
msbuild boohoo.dproj /p:Config=Release;ExtraDefines="hoo"
```

I did test adding the $(ExtraDefines) to the Include options for the project using the IDE. And at least that didn't barf at me, even without having the option defined in the dproj. The commandline the IDE produced from this was:

```
...rad studio\7.0\bin\dcc32.exe --no-config -B -Q -DDEBUG;DUNIT; -E....
```

Which seems to indicate that the $(ExtraDefines) got eliminated as it had no value. And that it should be picked up using MSBuild and specififying a value on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. Good thinking. I'll try this out as soon as I get to a machine.

Comment: Wonderful. That works beautifully. Really excellent thinking, thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 20):

Almost 5 years later, but all answers are not quite elegant ))

*Recently, I've faced the same problem*

And here is the solution:

Usually, DCC_Define is defined in a .dproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
    <DCC_Define>boo;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
```

We all have tried to define DCC_Define via `/property:DCC_Define=blah-blah`

But accordingly to [How to: Build the Same Source Files with Different Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171481(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The property value that is specified on the command line takes precedence over any value that is set for the same property in the project file, and that value in the project file takes precedence over the value in an environment variable.

So, failure (that is the question here!)

BUT! [How to: Use Environment Variables in a Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459(v=vs.100).aspx)

> To use an environment variable in an MSBuild project
>
> - Reference the environment variable the same way you would a variable    declared in your project file. For example, the following
>     code    references the BIN_PATH environment variable:
>
>   ```
>   <FinalOutput>$(BIN_PATH)\MyAssembly.dll</FinalOutput>
>   ```

So, we must define environment variable with the name `DCC_Define` and values of our ADDITIONAL conditionals

```
> set DCC_Define=hoo;doo;moo;foo
```

and then simply run

```
> msbuild boohoo.dproj /p:Config=Release
```

DCC32 will get then `-Dboo;hoo;doo;moo;foo`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant trick, definitely deserving much more upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward solution is to create a new build configuration (say, `boohooRelease`), add both `boo` and `hoo` conditional defines to it and compile as `msbuild boohoo.dproj /p:Config=boohooRelease`. Not exactly what you are trying to do, but it works.

Comment: Yes this would work but I'm looking for something lighter weight that decouples the dproj file from the build for when I want to build experimental versions of the code containing conditional code

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the following and it worked, so don't know whether Microsoft has changed it:

```
msbuild "myApp.dproj" /t:build /property:DCC_Define="boo"
```

remember to add the double quote "", otherwise it won't work

Comment: Beware that using this will overwrite any conditional defines listed in project settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a wrapper project file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Full" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Full">
  <CreateProperty Value="$(DCC_Define);$(ExtraDefines)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DCC_Define"/>
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>
<Import Project="example.dproj" />
</Project>
```

and invoke like this:

```
msbuild.exe "/t:Clean;Full;Build" "/p:config=Debug" /p:ExtraDefines=SOME_DEFINE wrapper.proj
```

It is certainly less elegant but you don't have to modify the .dproj file.